Old GTM account still appears in tag assistant
When I went to put in the GTM code into the header and footer it already had code in there so I deleted it and put in a new one. Even though I deleted it the GTM account still pops up in tag assistant legacy and the tag assistant page. Any ideas why and how to get rid of it?
Pretty much what I was trying to do was set up conversion tracking. The trigger I set up didn't fire so I thought the old account that I deleted but still appears could be causing some of the problems.

you mean the tag assistant legacy chrome extension that says [DEPRECATED] in its name? Do not use deprecated things. Open your DOM and look for the old GTM id.

By DOM do you mean the inspect page? And once I locate it there I should just delete it right?

once you locate it in the DOM (The Elements tab in devtools), you can trace it to whatever deploys it. Probably it's just hardcoded in a template or being added by a plugin.
